# Visual Studio 17.8.3 can't see a real Android device

Tags: android, visual-studio

I'm creating a new `MAUI` app with `NET8`; for that, I'm using Visual Studio 17.8.3. I use one real Android device (a Google Pixel 3) to test my apps — same mobile, same computer.

Now, when I open Visual Studio, I can't find my device in the list of available devices.

[image]

If I open the `Device Log` from Visual Studio, the device is connected and I can see the real-time logs.

[image]

When I run `adb devices`, I see the device.

[image]

In the Android device, I checked the `USB preferences`. I tried all of them with not luck.

[image]

The `Developer mode` is enabled.

[image]

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

please open Android emulator in the first picture that you sent.

Comment: And? I want to try to app on a real device.

Comment: Okay, send the photo after clicking on that button.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this case is related to the Android API version. If the `Application target` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` is greater than the version of the API on the device, the device is not visible in the list.

[image]